# C# Kinect v2: Access to ColorCameraSettings

Tags: c#, kinect

I am programming with the Kinect v2 in C# and I am interested in getting access to the ColorCameraSettings class.

In my C# program some RGB-IR pixel intensity values are stored for each frame in a file.

Now I also want to add the settings of the sensor (gain, gamma ...) for each of these frames. The ColorCameraSettings class is supposed to contain this information but the MSDN documentation doesn't provide example C# code snippets how to access it.

Does anybody know how to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Mawg, the gain and gamma values are available when you are writing the code in C# for the creation of the corresponding bitmaps.

Comment: But my question is, how I can read out these values for each frame. Do they have to be accessed when the current frame is locked?

Comment: Exactly that. Once you "save" the frame, you can "watch" this values